# cordova build crosswalk peer not authtenicated via proxy

Tags: android, cordova, maven, proxy, crosswalk

I'm trying to build my cordova but I'm behind a corporate proxy and i'm getting some errors:

> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'.
> >
> > > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:15+.
> > >            Required by:
> > >                :android:unspecified
> > >
> > > > Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library.
> > > >
> > > > > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml.
> > > > >
> > > > > > Could not GET 'http://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > > > > >
> > > > > > > peer not authenticated

I had to change the maven stuff in my build.gradle to fix some errors for building cordova

Anyone got a clue on how to get it to work?
I tried different versions of the xwalk library

*Note:I have a fiddler running that can get trough the proxy*

Answer (score 0):

You should update the Crosswalk plugin. The maven2 repository of Crosswalk doesn's use http anymore. And the latest version is xwalk_core_library:18+